# Starting Tomcat through web.config in IIS

Tags: iis, tomcat

I'm attempting to use IIS/HttpPlatformHandler as a frontend for Tomcat and while I've managed to get it working, I've noticed a couple of quirks. The one I'm currently scratching my head over involves Tomcat not starting via the web.config file in IIS. I noticed that when I created the web.config file and added the path to the Tomcat startup.bat file, it didn't seem to make Tomcat start. When I looked at the Tomcat logs, I found that there were none. It wasn't until I manually ran the Tomcat startup.bat that the log files were actually created.

Any ideas?

Comment: HttpPlatformHandler only launches the backend server (Tomcat in your case) upon first request to this server, so you won't see Tomcat running if no request comes yet. If you want an always running Tomcat instead, you should not use HttpPlatformHandler, but set up IIS as a pure reverse proxy server with ARR.

Comment: @LexLi, the thing is, when I made (what I thought was) a request to Tomcat, nothing seemed to happen. It wasn't until I manually went in and ran the Tomcat startup.bat that I was able to get things working. Perhaps I've missed something along the way?

Comment: Then you have to reveal your settings in web.config.

Comment: @LexLi, I apologize for being a bit dense but what do you mean by 'reveal your settings in web.config'? Post the settings here?